# Merge Two Complicated Lists in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, merge

I Have a Scenario.

Object Hierarchy as below:

a)Two Objects is there.

for eg. A.com,B.Com

a)List of Cards are there in the Each Object.

for eg. VISA,MasterCard.etc.

b)Each Card Contains Multiple Installment Number and Interest Rates
for eg. 2.2,3.3.etc

Now I have to Merge two Objects by means of certain restriction.

1)Priority is Always to A.Com,Means two common Installment occurs in A.com and B.com then Rates in A.com will Take.

2)If No Rates Occurs in A.com but in B.com,Rate in B.com will be Take.

Below Picture Gives a better idea:
[image: Merge idea]

I need to Implement this by Using Linq.
Please Help me guys as i am Stuck for some days in this and newbie in Linq.

Comment: What do you mean by *using linq*? Using linq function? Then what linq function? What data structure are you using? It seems like it's key-value pairs, not a list.

Comment: Exactly i mean Linq Function.and it is not a key Value Pair.

Comment: @Are you extracting these list with help of linq query? share your model and the way you stored this

Comment: If you want to extract data using LINQ, your source sequences should be `IQueryable<...>` or `IEnumerable<...>`. Please edit your question and add (relevant parts of) descriptions of the classes in your sequences. Also define your requirement more clearly: what is an Installment? When are two installments common? Apparently Installments have rates? What do you want to do with the Rates? Please add proper requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat), [`Lookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2) and [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) together. You did not show us your object definition so that I assume:

**Class Definition**

```
public class InstallmentInterestRate
{
    public int Installment { get; set; }
    public double Interest { get; set; }
}
public class Acom
{
    public List<InstallmentInterestRate> Visa { get; set; }
    public List<InstallmentInterestRate> MS { get; set; }
    public List<InstallmentInterestRate> AX { get; set; }
}

public class Bcom
{
    public List<InstallmentInterestRate> Visa { get; set; }
    public List<InstallmentInterestRate> MS { get; set; }
    public List<InstallmentInterestRate> AX { get; set; }
}
```

**Linq:**

```
Acom acom = new Acom()
{
    Visa = new List<InstallmentInterestRate>()
    {
        new InstallmentInterestRate(){ Installment = 1, Interest = 2.2},
        //other values
    },
    MS = new List<InstallmentInterestRate>()
    {
        new InstallmentInterestRate(){ Installment = 1, Interest = 2.2},
        //other values
    },
    AX = new List<InstallmentInterestRate>()
    {
        new InstallmentInterestRate(){ Installment = 1, Interest = 2.2},
        //other values
    }
};

Bcom bcom = new Bcom()
{
    Visa = new List<InstallmentInterestRate>()
    {
        new InstallmentInterestRate(){ Installment = 1, Interest = 2.2},
        //other values
    },
    MS = new List<InstallmentInterestRate>()
    {
        new InstallmentInterestRate(){ Installment = 1, Interest = 4.0},
        //other values
    },
    AX = new List<InstallmentInterestRate>()
    {
        new InstallmentInterestRate(){ Installment = 1, Interest = 2.2},
        //other values
    }
};

var merged = new
{
    Visa = acom.Visa.Concat(bcom.Visa)
        .ToLookup(p => p.Installment)
        .Select(g => g.Aggregate((p1, p2) => new InstallmentInterestRate
        {
            Installment = p1.Installment,
            Interest = p1.Interest
        })).ToList(),
    MS = acom.MS.Concat(bcom.MS)
        .ToLookup(p => p.Installment)
        .Select(g => g.Aggregate((p1, p2) => new InstallmentInterestRate
        {
            Installment = p1.Installment,
            Interest = p1.Interest
        })).ToList(),
    AX = acom.AX.Concat(bcom.AX)
        .ToLookup(p => p.Installment)
        .Select(g => g.Aggregate((p1, p2) => new InstallmentInterestRate
        {
            Installment = p1.Installment,
            Interest = p1.Interest
        })).ToList(),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Demo below

Efficiency warning: This is fine to get a one-liner for tiny lists as shown but for larger ones consider sorted lists to allow O(m+n) merge instead of O(m*n).

```
  class Program
  {
    private static readonly List<Tuple<int, double>> A = new List<Tuple<int, double>>
                                                         {
                                                           new Tuple<int, double>(1, 2.2),
                                                           new Tuple<int, double>(2, 2.3),
                                                           new Tuple<int, double>(3, 2.4)
                                                         };
    private static readonly List<Tuple<int, double>> B = new List<Tuple<int, double>>
                                                         {
                                                           new Tuple<int, double>(1, 2.2),
                                                           new Tuple<int, double>(3, 3.1),
                                                           new Tuple<int, double>(6, 3.4)
                                                         };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var merged = A.Concat(B.Where(iB => A.All(ia => ia.Item1 != iB.Item1)));
      Console.WriteLine("Merge(A,B): ");
      foreach (var (item1, item2) in merged) 
        Console.WriteLine($"  {item1}, {item2}");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
```

Produces

```
Merge(A,B):
  1, 2.2
  2, 2.3
  3, 2.4
  6, 3.4
```